# Convert URL to Bitmap results in a network error in Android

Tags: android, picasso, android-bitmap, loadimage

I'm trying to load an image from an URL to a Bitmap but I am getting a NetworkOnMainThreadException error but I don't know why.

This is the method I am using:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I also tried to load the image to a Target using Picasso library, because in the end, I want to get the dominant color from this image using Palette. This is the code I have using Picasso:

```
    Picasso.with(MovieDetails.this)
            .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + backdrop)
            .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    Palette palette = Palette.from(bitmap).generate();
                    System.out.println(palette.getVibrantSwatch().toString().substring(16, Math.min(palette.getVibrantSwatch().toString().length(), 22)));
                    LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_bg);
                    lLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+ palette.getVibrantSwatch().toString().substring(16, Math.min(palette.getVibrantSwatch().toString().length(), 22))));
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
```

I put this inside my onCreate method, but I am getting "method does not override method from its superclass" errors in all the three @Override methods.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem by using an AsyncTask as it follows:

I put this in the end of my Activity:

```
public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + backdrop);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Please note that inside this method I put the URL for the image.

To access the Bitmap inside my Activity and get the dominant color using Palette I did this:

```
MyAsync obj = new MyAsync(){

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) {
                super.onPostExecute(bmp);

                Bitmap bm = bmp;

                if (bm != null && !bm.isRecycled()) {
                    Palette palette = Palette.from(bm).generate();
                    System.out.println(palette.getVibrantSwatch().toString().substring(16, Math.min(palette.getVibrantSwatch().toString().length(), 22)));
                    LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_bg);
                    lLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+ palette.getVibrantSwatch().toString().substring(16, Math.min(palette.getVibrantSwatch().toString().length(), 22))));
                }


            }
        };

        obj.execute();
```

This code is inside my onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

The way to correct the first issue is to perform that action in a Thread or Runnable, There is a flag you can set something like StrictModeEnabled or something like that, but that's bad, don't resort to that.

As far as picasso, i dont know about the overriding methods from superclass thing, i'd try to do it in onViewCreated instead of onCreate

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How should I handle the thread? I created the 'new thread', 'run()', 'try' and inside 'while (true)'I have: 'sleep(1000);' 'handler.post(this);'. How should I put inside the Thread? And what do I do with the other methods that depend on the result of this method?